# How to set the background color for every page tcpdf

Tags: php, html, css, pdf-generation, tcpdf

I'm currently using TCPDF to generate a resume in my web application. But with the limited support for css have cornered me.
Now I'm trying to apply the background color for the every page that is generated. But I'm only getting the color for the first page.

My code is:

```
<?php
class PROFILE_PDF extends TCPDF
{
    public function Header()
    {
        $this->SetFillColor(52, 21, 0, 76);
        $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "");
    }


    private $footer_data = array();


    public function Footer()
    {
        // Position at 15 mm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Set font
        $this->SetFont('helvetica', 'I', 8);
        // Page number


        $name = <<< EOD
        <p>Curriculum Vitae - {$this->footer_data["name"]}</p>
        <style>
            p {
                color: #F5F5F5;
            }
        </style>

        EOD;
        $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 10, '', '', $name, 0, 1, 0, true, 'L', true);

        $page = <<< EOD

        <p>Page  {$this->getAliasNumPage()} /   {$this->getAliasNbPages()}</p>
        <style>
            p {
                color: #F5F5F5;
            }
        </style>

        EOD;

        $this->writeHTMLCell(0, 10, '', 284, $page, 0, 1, 0, true, 'R', true);

        $style = array('width' => 0.5, 'cap' => 'butt', 'join' => 'miter', 'dash' => 0, 'color' => array(128, 229, 255));
        $this->Line(0, 275, 250, 275, $style);
    }

    public function setFooterData($footer_data)
    {
        $this->footer_data = $footer_data;
    }

$pdf = new PROFILE_PDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);


$pdf->SetLineStyle(array('width' => 2, 'color' => array(112, 128, 144)));

$pdf->Line(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), 0);
$pdf->Line($pdf->getPageWidth(), 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0, $pdf->getPageHeight(), $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight());
$pdf->Line(0, 0, 0, $pdf->getPageHeight());

// set header data
$footer_data = array();
$footer_data["name"] = $personal_data["first_name"] . " " . $personal_data["last_name"];
$pdf->setFooterData($footer_data);

$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
//$pdf->Header();
// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(getSiteName());
$pdf->SetAuthor('Mobile Solutions');
$pdf->SetTitle($personal_data["first_name"] . " " . $personal_data["last_name"]);
$pdf->SetSubject("Student's profile");
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);

$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFillColor(52, 21, 0, 76);
$pdf->Rect(0, 0, $pdf->getPageWidth(), $pdf->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "");


$pdf->SetFont('courier', 'B', 24);

//some html elements

$pdf->Output($personal_data["first_name"] . "_" . $personal_data["last_name"] . ".pdf", 'D');
?>
```

Here I'm being unable to apply the `SetFillColor()` function to next generated pages. What's the reason for that? TCPDF documentation says it should be apply to all the pages.

Comment: you try to apply your fillColor on what ?

Comment: well i applied SetFillColor inside the header in order to apply for all the pages. Should it be changed?

Comment: This time i tried to get the number of the page and set the background color if the page number is larger than one. But it also doesn't work.

       if ($pdf->getAliasNumPage() > 1){

           
            $this->SetFillColor(52, 21, 0, 76);
            $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "");

        }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if you mean apply a background color with your `header` function you should apply the fill color directly on the `$pdf->rect` function in TCPDF

```
Rect( $x, $y, $w, $h, $style = '', $border_style = array(), $fill_color = array() )
```

so in your case it would be

```
$this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(),    $this->getPageHeight(), 'DF', "",  array(220, 220, 200));
```

where you have to change the array in the last argument to apply your color

It don't work because on TCPDF the fill color , as far as i know, will apply on the `cell` and `multicell` function if you specified the fill argument on true

[link on rect function TCPDF](https://tcpdf.org/docs/srcdoc/tcpdf/class-TCPDF/#_Rect)

```
foreach ($whatever as $data) {
    if($nextpage)
    {
         $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), 
                   'DF', "",  array(220, 220, 200)); // where the array is the color expected
    }
}
```

but the better option is to define it in the header and use as the example 51 on TCPDF
[link to the example](https://tcpdf.org/examples/example_051/)

```
public function Header() {
    // get the current page break margin
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
    // get current auto-page-break mode
    $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
    // disable auto-page-break
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
    // set bacground image
    $img_file = K_PATH_IMAGES.'image_demo.jpg';
    $this->Image($img_file, 0, 0, 210, 297, '', '', '', false, 300, '', false, false, 0);
    // restore auto-page-break status
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
    // set the starting point for the page content
    $this->setPageMark();
}
```

so here it's

```
public function Header() {
    // get the current page break margin
    $bMargin = $this->getBreakMargin();
    // get current auto-page-break mode
    $auto_page_break = $this->AutoPageBreak;
    // disable auto-page-break
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak(false, 0);
    $this->Rect(0, 0, $this->getPageWidth(), $this->getPageHeight(), 
               'DF', "",  array(220, 220, 200)); // where the array is the color expected
    $this->SetAutoPageBreak($auto_page_break, $bMargin);
    // set the starting point for the page content
    $this->setPageMark();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So how can I apply the color to the page instead for each and every cell?

Comment: please refer this question.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46291778/set-the-background-color-in-tcpdf

Comment: I found what was wrong.
I have misplaced this :

$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);